# Select rows that fall within Standard Deviation

Tags: mysql

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT    
    AVG(
      case 
         WHEN  `price` > (avg(`price`) - stddev_pop(`price`)) \
           AND `price` < (avg(`price`) + stddev_pop(`price`))
         THEN `price`
         ELSE NULL
      END)
FROM `history` 
WHERE `history`.`itemID` = 1574 \
      AND `date` > date_sub(now(), interval 30 DAY)
```

I am getting a #1111 - Invalid use of group function Error.

Basically, I want the average of `price` when `price` falls within standard deviation. If it does not, it should not be included in the **Avg**.

Example of `price`: 51, 48, 49, 56, 48, 56, 51, 58, 4, 56, 53

"4" should not be included while **Avg** is doing its thing.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean? that's an absurd question. to have an average, you must include all prices, then you can see which ones fall within stddev. You can't have it done at the same time.

Comment: You don't need to include all prices to get an average... If I have 51, 48, 49, 56, 48, 56, 51, 58, 4, 56, 53, I can easily get rid of 4 and still get an average excluding 4...

Comment: really? how do you decide to remove 4 from the list?

Comment: because it doesn't fall within average prices +- standard deviation

Comment: and the standard deviation is relative to what?

Comment: standard deviation is relative to all prices, obviously...

Comment: that's just horrible query. read how to use aggregate functions

Comment: look at your formula, the stddev compares to the avg. so, to remove 4, first you need to compute the avg including all prices, that is also 4.

Comment: I never said it was great query. I came here for some help.

Comment: @koriander I only want to exclude 4 from the very first avg, the next 2 can include 4.

Comment: sorry, that doesn't make any sense. You can compute the avg and stddev of all prices and THEN compute a new average removing the prices falling outside the initial deviation.

Comment: @koriander that's exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've provided an answer, you need to adapt it to your schema and add the WHERE clause to both selects (or only one, depending on what you want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4905c/2

```
select avg(price)
from prices
join (select avg(price) myavg, stddev_pop(price) mydev from prices) stats
where price between stats.myavg - stats.mydev and stats.myavg + stats.mydev
```

Comment: Thank you, Koriander. That is what I wanted.

Comment: That is calculating it for a 30 days interval. I also need 180,90,60, and 7 days. Will I run into any performance issues by using subselects?

Comment: last time I checked the manual, it mentioned subqueries where not as optimised as joins, but that should not be a problem here, since the join is trivial (1 row). The major computation really are the calculations which have to use all rows in an interval (twice). Not much to be done unless you keep stats precomputed.

Comment: btw, I saw that you tried to edit and used an INNER JOIN. You can't do that that, you need the cartesian product that I used ther.